# C# using <myowndll>, doesn't work (VS10 Express)

Tags: c#, dll, reference, using

**Background:** I am a novice in C#, and use Visual Studios 2010 Express.

I have a class (let's call it **myclass**) which I want to use in multiple projects. I used to add classes with Project->Add Existing Item... Which creates a copy of myclass.cs.

Now I just found out that when I build the original myclass.cs it creates a **myclass.dll** and places it in the release folder of my project.

But when I try to use this DLL, I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'myclass' could not be found(are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly refference?

Which is weird to me, because **I already have referenced it** (it is also in the Reference folder of my Solution Explorer). And I already have added this to my code:

```
using myclass;
```

So what am I doing wrong?

**Update:** When I tried my old method (add existing item -> myclass.cs) the error message goes away. So it's not a matter of spelling things correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I found the answer myself. It turns out that when you use the **using** function, it automatically searches for all public classes in the namespace you want to use.

If it can't find a public class, it refuses to recognize the DLL.

Furthermore, not specifying a class makes it internal.
So:

```
class myclass          // internal!
private class myclass // private!
public class myclass // only this makes it visible for others!
```

Everything was okay after changing *class myclass* into *public class myclass*.

Comment: classes by default (when unspecified) are `internal`.

Comment: That's useful information! Is there a difference between internal and private?

Comment: Yes, `internal` is accessible from within the same assembly (by any class in the assembly). `private` is only accessible from within the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Add the dll first:

Click on references in your project-explorer in visual studio and add your dll then you can use it as you expected it.

Comment: I already Referenced it I think?
"Which is weird to me, because I already have referenced it (it is also in Reference folder of my Solution Explorer)."

Comment: does your dll shows up in your project-explorer in visual studio under reference?

Comment: See my question:
"(it is also in Reference folder of my Solution Explorer). And I already have added this to my code:"

Comment: Well maybe you type your namespace wrong? I can't think of any other issues. Intellisense should give you the correct name of the namespace.

Comment: I copied the namespace from the original myclass.cs file but that didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure the namespace is correct and you didn't use your classname?

Comment: I'm sure, because when I use my old method (Project->Add Existing Item...) and add myclass.cs, the "using myclass" stops giving an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Add the reference in your project and check that the target Framework version of that assembly fits the project.

Check the namespaces inside the assembly and then use them like:

```
using YourAssemblyNamespace.class
```

Comment: It doesn't even recognize the namespace, let alone the classes in that namespace.